# Get list of files and programs touched by AS400/iSeries service account

Tags: sql, permissions, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get a list of the programs (RPG/CL/SQL) and files a service account on the iSeries has touched. The idea is that having this list we can tie specific permissions (I know this will really complicate things) to the user account in order to achieve a more secure application specific service account. Is there any way to do this and maybe get a report by running a command. Maybe there is a SQL statement?

Please excuse me if my terms are not appropriate, I am still new to the iSeries.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to know what objects a particular user account has _ever_ touched. You can look at journals but they usually only store information for the last X days (it's configurable). Here's some [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahg%2Frzahgicsecurity.htm) regarding security on the IBM i.

Comment: When you say "service account", exactly what do you mean? We normally refer to User Profiles (*USRPRF objects). But there can be other types of access. For example, a web server can be configured to allow users to login via a validation list (*VLDL object) which store UserID's and passwords. A UserID is validated by some application such as the web server, but is NOT related to aUser Profile.

Comment: WarrenT- What I mean by service account is an account created specifically to allow the execution of stored procedures (or SQL statements) in order to send data to a Web application. I am not sure it is the same as an actual iSeries user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audit journal will have what you are looking for....if so configured.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzarl/rzarlusesecjnl.htm

The newest 7.1 TR includes stored procedures to allow easy read of journals.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/DISPLAY_JOURNAL%20(easier%20searches%20of%20Audit%20Journal)

Charles

Comment: Interesting and likely it is the right and thorough answer. However I was looking for something one do that does not require much setup or any additional privileges.

Comment: Assuming a reasonably secure system.. The security audit journal should already be set up.  The only thing you'd need to have done would be to CHGUSRAUD SVCPRFNAM *ALL.

Answer (score 0):

So though Charles' answer might be the one one should set up to get a thorough report. I wound up doing the following as suggested by one of my peers.

Please note that my goal though not properly explained as so, was to create an application specific user/service account for a program. This is to avoid using one with many privileges and thus gain some security.

1.Go through the source code (in my case classic ASP) and jot down all the names of the procedures used by that program. 
2.Create a CL program that outputs the program references to a display file. Then export the file's contents onto Excel and massage where necessary.

```
PGM 
DSPPGMREF  PGM(MYLIB/PGM001) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/DSPPGMREF) OUTMBR(*FIRST *REPLACE)
DSPPGMREF  PGM(MYLIB/PGM002) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/DSPPGMREF) OUTMBR(*FIRST *ADD)
ENDPGM
```

I was told however that service programs references cannot be displayed with DSPPGMREF. So the following was done for those.

```
PGM                                                                                             
ADDLIBLE LIB(ABSTRACT) POSITION(*LAST)                                                          
MONMSG MSGID(CPF0000)                                                                           
WRKOBJR OBJ(SRVPGM01) OBJTYPE(*SRVPGM) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/WRKOBJR) MBROPT(*REPLACE)
WRKOBJR OBJ(SRVPGM02) OBJTYPE(*SRVPGM) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/WRKOBJR) MBROPT(*ADD)    
WRKOBJR OBJ(SRVPGM03) OBJTYPE(*SRVPGM) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/WRKOBJR) MBROPT(*ADD)    
ENDPGM
```

Thank you for all your help. I apologize that my answer is a little more specific than my question but in the end this was what I wanted to achieve, I had to generalize to ask the question. I'd thought i'd post post my answer anyways in case it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Do you have any kind of Change Management System (CMS?)  most include such x-ref facilities.  Or there are also stand alone tools.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your original question.  You're only finding out the dependent objects for a given set of programs.  Not all "programs and files" a service profile has touched.

Comment: You are right Charles. My question should have been posed differently. Yes we use Aldon CMS.

Comment: In an Aldon work with screen, Use option 41 or 42=Act upon dependent objects to find out what uses a certain object.  Or option 39=Display requisite objects to see what's used by an object.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Charles! Options 41 and 42 will come in really useful in my future endeavors with iSeries programs. I really appreciate your help.